# How is class A * A; declaration parsed by C++?

Tags: c++, class, types, specifications

I'm considering an example from the official spec:

```
class A * A;
```

I've read that this line introduces the two names: `class A` which can be accessed via elaborated-specifier-type only and pointer to A. Is this line fully equivalent to the two following lines?

```
class A;
A * A;
```

Is that line just syntax sugar and actually we have two lines as I've specified above? Or how is `class A * A;` parsed by compiler?

Comment: what does A*A line do, dosen't make sense

Comment: @TejasPatel it declares a variable `A` of type `A*`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore In the second example, wouldn't it call an operator * if it exists?

Comment: @AdriC.S. no, it's a declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the inline declaration is just syntactic sugar. You're forward-declaring that name **and** using it on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm trying to found some about it in the spec. Can you give me reference?

Comment: also, the fact that you _can_ declare a variable with the same name (case and all) as a class does not mean you _should_ do it. :D

Comment: I don't understand why this line is valid in c++. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv sorry, nope - go through the standard and fine one if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks you for your help again. I follow you advice and found this in the spec. I've decided to post additional answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm looking for more detailed answer in the working draft N3797 and I've found the following:

**§8.3.3**:

> Thus, a declaration of a particular identifier has the form `T D`
>   where `T` is of the form `attribute-specifier-seq_*opt* decl-specifier-seq` and `D` is a declarator.

**§7.1**:

```
decl-specifier:
    storage-class-specifier
    type-specifier
    function-specifier
    friend
    typedef
    constexpr
decl-specifier-seq:
    decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seq_*opt*
    decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq
```

**§7.1.6**:

```
type-specifier:
    trailing-type-specifier
    class-specifier
    enum-specifier
```

**§8.3.1**:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form 
>   `* attribute-specifier-seq_*opt* cv-qualifier-seq_*opt* D1` and the type of the 
>   identifier in the declaration `T D1` is “derived-declarator-type-list `T`,” then the 
>   type of the identifier of `D` is “derived-declarator-type-list cv-qualifier-seq pointer to `T`.”

Now `class-specifier` contains `class` keyword inside. Hence `class A * A` is valid grammar construction, where `* A` is declarator.